# Trouble with Paypal express checkout button on Pixafy(Magento)

Tags: paypal

Built a website on Pixafy, which has integrated Paypal payments, whenever i click the 'pay with paypal' button on either an item page or the checkout, it simply refreshes the checkout page.

I have it working on my other website, but i literally have no idea what has went wrong. Any help would be appreciated and more information can be provided. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Eren – This is Pixafy Support! Glad we were able to find your message. We apologize for the issue you’re experiencing. The cause is either invalid credentials or a duplicate invoice. We can’t be sure which it is without looking through your exception log. Can you please contact support@pixafy.com to get that process started?

Thanks for building on Pixafy!